# Make an overlapped view

Tags: ios, uiview

I would like to make two `UIViews`.  One of them will be fixed in the background with less opacity and the other above will be scrollable. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Its quite simple to do that implementation. You create 2 UIView's in the NIB file, one above the other ( in an hierarchy point of view). YOu can set the opacity of the one above, so you can see the one behind. Then, just drop an UIScrollView in the front one. If you need more help with specifics just reply. :)

Comment: Hi, thx for your post, in the main view shall add a UIView or a UIViewController?

Comment: the XIB file, shall i get two UIView or UIViewControllers?

Comment: I personally prefere UIViewControllers, because then the init and releases are handled by the computer.